# Can't see Connections or Triggers in Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm a total beginner when it comes to Azure, but I created a Data Factory following different guides and no matter which one I use I can't see connections or triggers in the Factory resources tab under Author & Monitor. I must be missing something trivial and I can't find anyone that seems to have the same problem as I do.

[What I see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45qT1.png)

[What I'm missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VRTb.png)

I clearly have no clue why they aren't showing up in the bottom left corner, anyone savvy enough to help me out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These were recently moved to here:

[image]

Comment: I was going crazy searching for it... Thank you kindly : )

Answer (score 1):

In latest ADF, there is no upfront option like connection-->Linked service available instead Linked service option there only during creating the new dataset.